# Visual Studio Code and Webpack

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-code, sass

I have a _variables.scss file that i'm importing into a project.
Then I export the variables to make them available.

variables.scss

```
:root 
{
 --WebPartWidth: 900px;
}
```

Now I export them to a Globals file:

```
:export 
{
 WebPartWidth: #{var(--WebPartWidth)};
}
```

Then I put all my SCC & SCSS stuff together and import them into my main class using a master style sheet:

```
import * as styles from './MasterCSS.module.scss';
```

Which allows me to reference them like so:

```
styles.default.WebPartWidth
```

The issue i'm having is, the value is a string "var(--WebPartWidth)" and not the actual underlying value.

I don't know anything about webpack and how to configure it or even set it up so, I'm wondering if this is something that webpack is doing or is it something i'm doing wrong?

any help would be great!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy cow...
So after much reading and testing I figured out how to do what I wanted to do.

The idea was to hook my SCSS global variables to some CSS variables and be able to cascade changes throughout my project by updating the CSS variable value.

**Environment**:
 1. Sharepoint Online  -- No Javascript Framework
 2. Visual Studio Code -- Latest
 3. Typescript -- Latest
 4. Gulp -- 3.9.1

**Goal**:
Allow users to change various CSS properties via the Property Pane. Changes should cascade throughout the entire project.
I need to be able to do this **without** messing with Webpack or gulpfile.js.

**Pieces**:

Custom function to map values:
**_Utility.scss**

```
// map-value
// @access public
// @param {$key} -- Item to Map
@function map-value($key)
{
  @if type-of($key) == "string"
  {
     @return to-string($key);
  }
  @else
  {
     @return val($key);
  }
}

@function to-string($key)
{
   @return inspect( val($key) );
}

@function val($key)
{
  // Return value:
  @return var($key);
}
```

**-- EOF**

**_Variables.scss**
I put these at the top of the file.

```
$WebPartWidth: 900px;
$WebPartMinimumWidth: 800px;
$WebPartMaximumWidth: 1000px;

$WebPartHeight: 500px;
$WebPartMinimumHeight: 400px;
$WebPartMaximumHeight: 600px;
```

Next I create my CSS variables and link them to the SCSS variables.

```
:root
{
  --WebPartWidth: #{$WebPartWidth};
  --WebPartMinimumWidth: #{$WebPartMinimumWidth};
  --WebPartMaximumWidth: #{$WebPartMaximumWidth};

  --WebPartHeight: #{$WebPartHeight};
  --WebPartMinimumHeight: #{$WebPartMinimumHeight};
  --WebPartMaximumHeight: #{$WebPartMaximumHeight};
}
```

**-- EOF**

Now, I create my Global file.

**Global.module.scss**

```
@import './Variables';

:export
{
  WebPartWidth: #{$WebPartWidth};
  WebPartMinimumWidth: #{$WebPartMinimumWidth};
  WebPartMaximumWidth: #{$WebPartMaximumWidth};

  WebPartHeight: #{$WebPartHeight};
  WebPartMinimumHeight: #{$WebPartMinimumHeight};
  WebPartMaximumHeight: #{$WebPartMaximumHeight};
}
```

**-- EOF**

And finally, I pull it all together in my main CSS file.

**Webpart.module.scss**

```
// Import our functions:
@import "./Utility";

// Import our Global Variables:
@import "./Global.module.scss";

.Webpart {
  width: map-value(--WebPartWidth);
  min-width: map-value(--WebPartMinimumWidth);
  max-width: map-value(--WebPartMaximumWidth);
  height: map-value(--WebPartHeight);
  min-height: map-value(--WebPartMinimumHeight);
  max-height: map-value(--WebPartMaximumHeight);
}
```

**-- EOF**

In my typescript file
**Webpart.ts**

```
import * as styles from './WebPart.module.scss';
```

And now, I can adjust the values like so:

```
document.body.style.setProperty('--WebPartWidth', newValue + "px");
```

And now, anything that references the --WebPartWidth CSS variable gets updated and the new value is applied.

I really hope this helps someone. I know I spent quite a while trying to figure this out.  Happy coding!